# Find a specific class under a div to process child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Allow me to paste the HTML first that I am hoping to process.

```
<div class="top-box-part">

    <h3 class="video-link-on-search">
        <a href="#">My Title</a>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="colorbox-inline-1449860223">
                <div class="jwplayer-video">...</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </h3>

    <h3 class="search-title"><a href="#">My Another Title</a></h3>

</div>

<div class="top-box-part">

    <h3 class="video-link-on-search">
        <a href="#">My Title 2</a>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="colorbox-inline-1449860223">

            </div>

        </div>
    </h3>

    <h3 class="search-title"><a href="#">My second another title</a></h3>

</div>
```

As you can see there are two `<h3>` in the div. What I am hoping to do is, to show one `<h3>` in main div `top-box-part`. If the first `<h3 class='video-link-on-search'>` has `jwplayer-video` in it, then show this , and hide the second `<h3 class='search-title'>`, otherwise, hide the first `h3 class='video-link-on-search'` and show the second `<h3 class='search-title'>`.

There are many `<div class='top-box-part'>` in the page and each is with two `<h3>`. We only have one to show one `<h3>` in each.

Comment: why wouldn't you set an id for each h3 tag?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: can you change HTML on the page? If you can than just add some distinct class names and work with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `find()`

```js
$('.top-box-part').each(function() {
  $(this).find('h3').hide();
  if ($(this).find('h3 .jwplayer-video').length) {
    $(this).find('h3:first').show();
  } else {
    $(this).find('h3:not(:first)').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-box-part">

  <h3 class="video-link-on-search">
        <a href="#">My Title</a>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="colorbox-inline-1449860223">
                <div class="jwplayer-video">...</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </h3>

  <h3 class="search-title"><a href="#">My Another Title</a></h3>

</div>

<div class="top-box-part">

  <h3 class="video-link-on-search">
        <a href="#">My Title 2</a>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="colorbox-inline-1449860223">

            </div>

        </div>
    </h3>

  <h3 class="search-title"><a href="#">My second another title</a></h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper selectors would be:

Every first h1 in every top_box-part:

```
var firsts = $('.top-box-part h3:nth-child(1)');
```

Every second h1 in every .top-box-part:

```
var seconds = $('.top-box-part h3:nth-child(2)');
```

Now you can simply check that like:

```
$.each(first,function(i,o){
   var first_element_of_current_top_box = o;
   var second_element_of_current_top_box = seconds[i];
   // here you can compare anything and do anything with those elements (ex. `.hasClass` etc.)
});
```

*Please note that this way needs 1st and 2nd H1 to be there!*